# Find out default screenshot path in MacOS from within Python to monitor screenshots

Tags: python, macos, directory, screenshot

I have a program that monitors for new screenshots but however, I had to change the default screenshot directory to /screenshots instead of the  in com.apple.screencapture

How can I obtain the directory set within com.apple.screencapture from within Python so that the program can run on any MacOS computer without having to manually change the screenshot directory location first.

Example code (currently after changing dir):

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'screenshots')
observer = Observer()
event_handler = ScreenshotEventHandler()
# Create a watchdog to watch <current_dir>/screenshots directory
observer.schedule(event_handler, path)
observer.start()
```

Comment: My first guess (probably not the best solution, though) would be to use `plutil` (using the `subprocess` module) to query the appropriate `com.apple.screencapture` file.

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer at apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the shell command `defaults` to read the location.

```
filepath = os.system('defaults read com.apple.screencapture location')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import sys, os, time,re,json
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

    cmd = 'defaults read com.apple.screencapture location' # default env variable that stores the screenshot dir in MacOS 
    #opens a stream and retrieves output
    pipe = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True) 
    # reads the output from the stdout and then strips the '\n' at the end to form a valid path
    path = pipe.stdout.read().rstrip()
```

This is the answer I used.